# How to get Histogram of all columns in a large CSV / RDD[Array[double]] using Apache Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, histogram, rdd

I am trying to calculate Histogram of all columns from a CSV file using Spark Scala.

I found that DoubleRDDFunctions supporting Histogram. 
So I coded like following for getting histogram of all columns.

1. Get column count
2. Create `RDD[double]`  of each column and calculate Histogram of each `RDD` using `DoubleRDDFunctions`

   ```
   var columnIndexArray = Array.tabulate(rdd.first().length) (_ * 1)

   val histogramData = columnIndexArray.map(columns => {
     rdd.map(lines => lines(columns)).histogram(6) 
   })
   ```

Is it a good way ?
Can anyone suggest some better ways to tackle this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not exactly better but alternative way is to convert a RDD to a DataFrame and use `histogram_numeric` UDF.

Example data:

```
import scala.util.Random
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{callUDF, lit, col}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext

val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)

Random.setSeed(1)

val ncol = 5

val rdd = sc.parallelize((1 to 1000).map(
  _ => Row.fromSeq(Array.fill(ncol)(Random.nextDouble))
))

val schema = StructType(
  (1 to ncol).map(i => StructField(s"x$i", DoubleType, false)))

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
df.registerTempTable("df")
```

Query:

```
val nBuckets = 3
val columns = df.columns.map(
  c => callUDF("histogram_numeric", col(c), lit(nBuckets)).alias(c))
val histograms = df.select(columns: _*)

histograms.printSchema

// root
//  |-- x1: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
//  |    |    |-- x: double (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- y: double (nullable = true)
//  |-- x2: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
//  |    |    |-- x: double (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- y: double (nullable = true)
//  |-- x3: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
//  |    |    |-- x: double (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- y: double (nullable = true)
//  |-- x4: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
//  |    |    |-- x: double (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- y: double (nullable = true)
//  |-- x5: array (nullable = true)
//  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
//  |    |    |-- x: double (nullable = true)
//  |    |    |-- y: double (nullable = true)

histograms.select($"x1").collect()

// Array([WrappedArray([0.16874313309969038,334.0],
//   [0.513382068667877,345.0], [0.8421388886903808,321.0])])
```

Comment: Its giving org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: undefined function histogram_numeric. I am using spark 1.5.1

Comment: UDFs require HiveContext.

Comment: thanks ... I have edited the variable name in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

the (scala api) transformation, *countByValue* ought to do what you want

so for instance to generate histogram data for the *first column* in your RDD:

```
val histCol1 = RDD.map(record => record.col_1).countByValue()
```

in the expression above, *record* just refers to a data row in the RDD, an instance of a case class that has a field col_1

and so *histCol1* will return a hash table (Scala Map) in which the keys are the unique values in column 1 (col_1) and the values are obviously the frequencies of each unique value

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But i need to give bucket size also.Maximum buckets 10. countByValue() will work efficient than double RDD's histogram ?

Comment: "bucket size" is in fact returned by countByValue--each value is the size of the bucket, while the key is the bucket name

Comment: can we fix the bucket size to one value ? instead of considering the distinct count. I do not need all distinct count, i need histogram with maximum buckets 10.

Comment: 1. Apply Binning with maximum bucket number , 2. Apply countByValue